# How to Launch a function using threads in Perl

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have tried to call a function using threads using perl in my windows system.
But, during the execution, when i click the button to create a thread process, Microsoft error message is displayed as shown below,

"Perl Command Line Interpreter.
Please tell Microsoft about this problem."

Code Snippet i used in Perl:

```
use threads;

#####  Creation of a dialog box using Tkx Module #####
$Run = $MainFrame -> new_ttk__button(
          -text => TEXT,
          -width => 15,
          -command => sub
                       {
                         threads -> create({"stack_size" => 64*4096,
                                            "exit" => "thread_only"},
                         \&CALLING_FUNCTION);
                       }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Tk having difficulties with threads: [Perl Update UI on Long Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782543/perl-update-ui-on-long-thread)

You need to create your thread before the Tk objects, maybe it is going to work this way.

> However, using threads with Tkx may be dicey. I was getting segfaults
>   when I tried to join the thread rather than detach it, and I get a
>   segfault with the code below if I move my $t inside startWork(). This
>   discussion suggests that you may need to start the thread before
>   creating any Tk widgets for it to work reliably.
>
> Your problem comes because you are letting Tk code get copied into
>   your thread, by starting it late in the script. When a thread gets
>   launched, a copy of the main thread is made, so if there are Tk
>   widgets already in existence, they get copied in. Even if you don't
>   use the Tk code in the thread, it can cause problems, and will be
>   unreliable. So...... create your thread first, before starting any Tk
>   widget code.